# previous activity state after launching new activity in its onCreate method?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Can any one explains what happens if I execute this activity?
I am getting weird output and app is hanging.

```
public class ComedyAct extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new ProgressBar(this));

        startActivity(new Intent(this,secondact.class));

        Log.d("main","I am after start second act");
        int i=0;
        while(i<10000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        int i=0;
        while(i<10000);
        Log.d("main","I am in start first act");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        int i=0;
        while(i<10000);
        Log.d("main","I am in stop first act");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not put a debug point at  `while(i<10000);` in onCreate and use a debugger to figure out whats happenning

Comment: @Raghunandan I am more interested what will happen and why it will happen if I write such a code than mere output.

Comment: you should figure that out if you debug with the helper of a debugger

Comment: I can but based on that i cannot assume how android system deals with the activities based on the output. I need some explantion regarding.. what happens when I launch an activity in oncreate of an activity,  what about statemets after the oncreate of previous activity?. If they can execute(yes) , that means there are two threads(UI) rendering the UI or main operations of app(one is drawing new act on screen other on executing previous act ). How could it be? there will be only one mainUIThread as far as i know.

Comment: yes it does. You have just one thread that is the ui thread. Besides with debugger you will figure that out yourself what is the flow of execution

Comment: what you mean by yes it does?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154327/discussion-between-ajay-reddy-and-raghunandan).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to read the activity life cycle...

when you start another activity, the ComedyAct  activity will be in stop state, onStart will never call in this case..

Activity life cycle is:

OnCreate---> OnStart--->OnResume

when another activity launches
then first of all onPause---->onStop--->onDestroy

when first activity will be on resume?

first of all onCreate---->--->onStart---->onResume, if activity is destroyed...

But if the activity is not destroyed..then first of all onRestart--->onStart--->OnResume, in this case onCreate will never be called...

Comment: Pls run the code and ans. Becoz it will giving unexpected output. Explain the output.